# How to use bquote in combination with ggplot2 geom_label?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

I've read the following article:
https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/2246/

Now I'm trying to use the suggested approach with `bquote` in my plot. However I can't get it to work. I have the following code

```r
x <- seq(0, 2*pi, 0.01)
y <- sin(x)
y_median <- median(y)
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_label(aes(label = bquote("median" ~ y==~.y_median), x = 1, y = y_median))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"formula"’ to a data.frame
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot doesn't like to work with expressions for labels in `geom_text` or `geom_label` layers. It likes to work with strings. So instead you can do

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  annotate("text", label = deparse(bquote("median" ~ y==~.(y_median))), x = 1, y = y_median, parse=TRUE)
```

We use `deparse()` to turn it into a string, then use `parse=TRUE` to have ggplot parse it back into an expression. Also I just used `annotate()` here since you aren't really mapping this value to your data at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_label(aes(label = list(bquote("median" ~ y==~.(y_median))),
                 x = 1, y = y_median), 
             parse=TRUE)
```

Key points:

1.) I fixed the missing parentheses in `"median" ~ y==~.(y_median)`. This is discussed in `?bquote` help page:

> ‘bquote’ quotes its
>        argument except that terms wrapped in ‘.()’ are evaluated in the
>        specified ‘where’ environment.

2.) Put the `bquote` inside a list, because `aes` expects a vector or a list.

3.) Tell `geom_label` to parse the expression by the setting the corresponding parameter to TRUE.

[image]